# Samsung Galaxy stops synchronizing Exchange ActiveSync account after every OS update

Tags: calendar, exchange, accounts, active-sync

On Samsung Galaxy S10 Exchange ActiveSync (outlook365) account stops synchronizing after each Samsung OS update.
Our corporate IT policy requires a PIN to access the device when using the Android client.
I needed always to delete and recreate the ActiveSync account to make it sync again.
Today I have tried to just open the settings of Exchange server under setting/accounts in E-mail application and confirm it and it somehow started to sync again.
Any clue how to easily fix those problems and what is the cause?

Comment: Couldn't you just ask your Corporate IT section what controls the signature that ActiveSync needs for authentication? It probably includes multiple fluid parts, some more than others, that can change over time: your specific Outlook Account (not generally mutable), the device ID (not mutable), a signature from the OS version (mutable, but specific).

Comment: It is difficult with the IT section. But it is outlook.office365.com exchange account, so it should behave in some standard manner? The device is quarantined first, then they mark the quarantined device as an authorized device, that's what they do I believe.There is Device ID which should be unique.